# Setting environment variables in eclipse that references other environment variables

Tags: eclipse, variables, environment

I have Eclipse Helios with a java program set up. I'm attempting to create two environment variables

ReportingManagerHome=C:\rp
ReportingManagerConfig=${ReportingManagerHome}\config

I then run my program with

System.out.println(System.getenv("ReportingManagerConfig"));

Eclipse doesn't even call the java compiler. It throws up a pop up window with the error that environment variable  ReportingManagerHome is not defined. I understand that since the java compiler has yet to be called, technically Eclipse is correct.

Now how do I work around this so that I can define cascading environment variables in Eclipse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't recursively expand environment variables from the launch config.

Even using `${env:VAR}` takes it from the environment variables from your eclipse process, not from your current launch config.

The most reliable way to do it is to go to *Preferences>Run/Debug>String Substitution* and define an eclipse variable there.

Then define the environment variables in your launch config:

```
ReportingManagerHome=${RMH}
ReportingManagerConfig=${RMH}\config
```

Comment: `${env:VAR}` should be `${env_var:VAR}`, at least in Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Mars and later you can use

```
${env_var:VAR_NAME}
```