# Eclipse String Substitution within New String Substitution Variable itself

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables, string-substitution

[In this eclipse string substitution question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307975/setting-environment-variables-in-eclipse-that-references-other-environment-varia) the answer tells one to declare environment variables in launch config like so:

> *Then define the environment variables in your launch config:*
>
> ReportingManagerHome=${RMH}
>
> ReportingManagerConfig=${RMH}\config

My questions are:

Couldn't I declare this environment variables there, instead?

Are Eclipse variables considered environment variables on their own?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse string substitution variables are not environment variables.

The only thing that knows about them is the Eclipse String Variable Manager (in the `org.eclipse.core.variables` plugin).

Comment: Will check that plugin. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @Alan I'd like to add that although Eclipse string substitution variables is a different thing that system environment variables it is possible to access the value of the latter from the former: `${env_var:SYS_ENV_VAR}`.